# KMP: Failing to add 'cafe.adriel.voyager' dependency

Tags: kotlin, gradle, kotlin-multiplatform

By using a wizard (https://kmp.jetbrains.com) I've created a sample project, but faced with an error to import "voyager" (https://voyager.adriel.cafe/setup):

```
# gradle/libs.versions.toml

[versions]
voyager = "1.1.0-alpha01"

[libraries]
voyager-navigator = { module = "cafe.adriel.voyager:voyager-navigator", version.ref = "voyager" }
voyager-screenModel = { module = "cafe.adriel.voyager:voyager-screenmodel", version.ref = "voyager" }
voyager-bottomSheetNavigator = { module = "cafe.adriel.voyager:voyager-bottom-sheet-navigator", version.ref = "voyager" }
voyager-tabNavigator = { module = "cafe.adriel.voyager:voyager-tab-navigator", version.ref = "voyager" }
voyager-transitions = { module = "cafe.adriel.voyager:voyager-transitions", version.ref = "voyager" }
```

```
# composeApp/build.gradle.kts

kotlin {
    sourceSets {
        commonMain.dependencies {
            implementation("cafe.adriel.voyager:voyager-navigator:1.1.0-alpha01")
            implementation("cafe.adriel.voyager:voyager-screenmodel:1.1.0-alpha01")
        }
    }
}
```

Taken the error for `gradlew build`:

```
$ gradlew run
Type-safe project accessors is an incubating feature.

> Configure project :composeApp
New 'wasm' target is Work-in-Progress and is subject to change without notice.
w: The following Kotlin/Native targets cannot be built on this machine and are disabled:
iosArm64, iosSimulatorArm64, iosX64
To hide this message, add 'kotlin.native.ignoreDisabledTargets=true' to the Gradle properties.


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':composeApp:wasmJsCompileClasspath'.
> Could not resolve cafe.adriel.voyager:voyager-navigator:1.1.0-alpha01.
  Required by:
      project :composeApp
   > No matching variant of cafe.adriel.voyager:voyager-navigator:1.1.0-alpha01 was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during 'kotlin-api', preferably optimized for non-jvm, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'wasm', attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.wasm.target' with value 'js' but:
       - Variant 'debugApiElements-published' capability cafe.adriel.voyager:voyager-navigator:1.1.0-alpha01 declares a library for use during compile-time:
           - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'wasm'
           - Other compatible attributes:
               - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
               - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.wasm.target (required 'js')
       - Variant 'debugRuntimeElements-published' capability cafe.adriel.voyager:voyager-navigator:1.1.0-alpha01 declares a library for use during runtime:
           - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'wasm'
           - Other compatible attributes:
               - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
               - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.wasm.target (required 'js')
       - Variant 'debugSourcesElements-published' capability cafe.adriel.voyager:voyager-navigator:1.1.0-alpha01 declares a component for use during runtime:
           - Incompatible because this component declares documentation, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' and the consumer needed a library, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'wasm'
           - Other compatible attributes:
               - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
               - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.wasm.target (required 'js')
       - Variant 'desktopApiElements-published' capability cafe.adriel.voyager:voyager-navigator:1.1.0-alpha01 declares a library for use during compile-time:
           - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'jvm' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'wasm'
           - Other compatible attributes:
               - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
               - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.wasm.target (required 'js')
       - Variant 'desktopRuntimeElements-published' capability cafe.adriel.voyager:voyager-navigator:1.1.0-alpha01 declares a library for use during runtime:
           - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'jvm' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'wasm'
           - Other compatible attributes:
               - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
               - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.wasm.target (required 'js')
       - Variant 'desktopSourcesElements-published' capability cafe.adriel.voyager:voyager-navigator:1.1.0-alpha01 declares a component for use during runtime:
           - Incompatible because this component declares documentation, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'jvm' and the consumer needed a library, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'wasm'
           - Other compatible attributes:
               - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
               - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.wasm.target (required 'js')
       - Variant 'iosArm64ApiElements-published' capability cafe.adriel.voyager:voyager-navigator:1.1.0-alpha01 declares a library for use during 'kotlin-api':
           - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'wasm'
           - Other compatible attributes:
               - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
               - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.wasm.target (required 'js')
       - Variant 'iosArm64MetadataElements-published' capability cafe.adriel.voyager:voyager-navigator:1.1.0-alpha01 declares a library:
           - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during 'kotlin-metadata', as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native' and the consumer needed a component for use during 'kotlin-api', as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'wasm'
           - Other compatible attributes:
               - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
               - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.wasm.target (required 'js')
       - Variant 'iosArm64SourcesElements-published' capability cafe.adriel.voyager:voyager-navigator:1.1.0-alpha01:
           - Incompatible because this component declares documentation for use during 'kotlin-runtime', as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native' and the consumer needed a library for use during 'kotlin-api', as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'wasm'
           - Other compatible attributes:
               - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
               - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.wasm.target (required 'js')
       - Variant 'iosSimulatorArm64ApiElements-published' capability cafe.adriel.voyager:voyager-navigator:1.1.0-alpha01 declares a library for use during 'kotlin-api':
           - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'wasm'
           - Other compatible attributes:
               - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
               - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.wasm.target (required 'js')
       - Variant 'iosSimulatorArm64MetadataElements-published' capability cafe.adriel.voyager:voyager-navigator:1.1.0-alpha01 declares a library:
           - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during 'kotlin-metadata', as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native' and the consumer needed a component for use during 'kotlin-api', as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'wasm'
           - Other compatible attributes:
               - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
               - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.wasm.target (required 'js')
       - Variant 'iosSimulatorArm64SourcesElements-published' capability cafe.adriel.voyager:voyager-navigator:1.1.0-alpha01:
           - Incompatible because this component declares documentation for use during 'kotlin-runtime', as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native' and the consumer needed a library for use during 'kotlin-api', as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'wasm'
           - Other compatible attributes:
               - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
               - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.wasm.target (required 'js')
       - Variant 'iosX64ApiElements-published' capability cafe.adriel.voyager:voyager-navigator:1.1.0-alpha01 declares a library for use during 'kotlin-api':
           - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'wasm'
           - Other compatible attributes:
               - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
               - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.wasm.target (required 'js')
       - Variant 'iosX64MetadataElements-published' capability cafe.adriel.voyager:voyager-navigator:1.1.0-alpha01 declares a library:
           - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during 'kotlin-metadata', as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native' and the consumer needed a component for use during 'kotlin-api', as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'wasm'
           - Other compatible attributes:
               - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
               - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.wasm.target (required 'js')
       - Variant 'iosX64SourcesElements-published' capability cafe.adriel.voyager:voyager-navigator:1.1.0-alpha01:
           - Incompatible because this component declares documentation for use during 'kotlin-runtime', as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native' and the consumer needed a library for use during 'kotlin-api', as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'wasm'
           - Other compatible attributes:
               - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
               - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.wasm.target (required 'js')
       - Variant 'jsApiElements-published' capability cafe.adriel.voyager:voyager-navigator:1.1.0-alpha01 declares a library for use during 'kotlin-api':
           - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'js' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'wasm'
           - Other compatible attributes:
               - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
               - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.wasm.target (required 'js')
       - Variant 'jsRuntimeElements-published' capability cafe.adriel.voyager:voyager-navigator:1.1.0-alpha01 declares a library:
           - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during 'kotlin-runtime', as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'js' and the consumer needed a component for use during 'kotlin-api', as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'wasm'
           - Other compatible attributes:
               - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
               - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.wasm.target (required 'js')
       - Variant 'jsSourcesElements-published' capability cafe.adriel.voyager:voyager-navigator:1.1.0-alpha01:
           - Incompatible because this component declares documentation for use during 'kotlin-runtime', as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'js' and the consumer needed a library for use during 'kotlin-api', as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'wasm'
           - Other compatible attributes:
               - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
               - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.wasm.target (required 'js')
       - Variant 'macosArm64ApiElements-published' capability cafe.adriel.voyager:voyager-navigator:1.1.0-alpha01 declares a library for use during 'kotlin-api':
           - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'wasm'
           - Other compatible attributes:
               - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
               - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.wasm.target (required 'js')
       - Variant 'macosArm64MetadataElements-published' capability cafe.adriel.voyager:voyager-navigator:1.1.0-alpha01 declares a library:
           - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during 'kotlin-metadata', as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native' and the consumer needed a component for use during 'kotlin-api', as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'wasm'
           - Other compatible attributes:
               - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
               - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.wasm.target (required 'js')
       - Variant 'macosArm64SourcesElements-published' capability cafe.adriel.voyager:voyager-navigator:1.1.0-alpha01:
           - Incompatible because this component declares documentation for use during 'kotlin-runtime', as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native' and the consumer needed a library for use during 'kotlin-api', as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'wasm'
           - Other compatible attributes:
               - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
               - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.wasm.target (required 'js')
       - Variant 'macosX64ApiElements-published' capability cafe.adriel.voyager:voyager-navigator:1.1.0-alpha01 declares a library for use during 'kotlin-api':
           - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'wasm'
           - Other compatible attributes:
               - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
               - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.wasm.target (required 'js')
       - Variant 'macosX64MetadataElements-published' capability cafe.adriel.voyager:voyager-navigator:1.1.0-alpha01 declares a library:
           - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during 'kotlin-metadata', as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native' and the consumer needed a component for use during 'kotlin-api', as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'wasm'
           - Other compatible attributes:
               - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
               - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.wasm.target (required 'js')
       - Variant 'macosX64SourcesElements-published' capability cafe.adriel.voyager:voyager-navigator:1.1.0-alpha01:
           - Incompatible because this component declares documentation for use during 'kotlin-runtime', as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native' and the consumer needed a library for use during 'kotlin-api', as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'wasm'
           - Other compatible attributes:
               - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
               - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.wasm.target (required 'js')
       - Variant 'metadataApiElements' capability cafe.adriel.voyager:voyager-navigator:1.1.0-alpha01 declares a library:
           - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during 'kotlin-metadata', as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'common' and the consumer needed a component for use during 'kotlin-api', as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'wasm'
           - Other compatible attributes:
               - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
               - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.wasm.target (required 'js')
       - Variant 'metadataSourcesElements' capability cafe.adriel.voyager:voyager-navigator:1.1.0-alpha01:
           - Incompatible because this component declares documentation for use during 'kotlin-runtime', as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'common' and the consumer needed a library for use during 'kotlin-api', as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'wasm'
           - Other compatible attributes:
               - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
               - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.wasm.target (required 'js')
       - Variant 'releaseApiElements-published' capability cafe.adriel.voyager:voyager-navigator:1.1.0-alpha01 declares a library for use during compile-time:
           - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'wasm'
           - Other compatible attributes:
               - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
               - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.wasm.target (required 'js')
       - Variant 'releaseRuntimeElements-published' capability cafe.adriel.voyager:voyager-navigator:1.1.0-alpha01 declares a library for use during runtime:
           - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'wasm'
           - Other compatible attributes:
               - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
               - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.wasm.target (required 'js')
       - Variant 'releaseSourcesElements-published' capability cafe.adriel.voyager:voyager-navigator:1.1.0-alpha01 declares a component for use during runtime:
           - Incompatible because this component declares documentation, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' and the consumer needed a library, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'wasm'
           - Other compatible attributes:
               - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
               - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.wasm.target (required 'js')
> Could not resolve cafe.adriel.voyager:voyager-screenmodel:1.1.0-alpha01.
  Required by:
      project :composeApp
   > No matching variant of cafe.adriel.voyager:voyager-screenmodel:1.1.0-alpha01 was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during 'kotlin-api', preferably optimized for non-jvm, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'wasm', attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.wasm.target' with value 'js' but:
       - Variant 'debugApiElements-published' capability cafe.adriel.voyager:voyager-screenmodel:1.1.0-alpha01 declares a library for use during compile-time:
           - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'wasm'
           - Other compatible attributes:
               - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
               - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.wasm.target (required 'js')
       - Variant 'debugRuntimeElements-published' capability cafe.adriel.voyager:voyager-screenmodel:1.1.0-alpha01 declares a library for use during runtime:
           - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'wasm'
           - Other compatible attributes:
               - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
               - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.wasm.target (required 'js')
       - Variant 'debugSourcesElements-published' capability cafe.adriel.voyager:voyager-screenmodel:1.1.0-alpha01 declares a component for use during runtime:
           - Incompatible because this component declares documentation, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' and the consumer needed a library, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'wasm'
           - Other compatible attributes:
               - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
               - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.wasm.target (required 'js')
       - Variant 'desktopApiElements-published' capability cafe.adriel.voyager:voyager-screenmodel:1.1.0-alpha01 declares a library for use during compile-time:
           - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'jvm' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'wasm'
           - Other compatible attributes:
               - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
               - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.wasm.target (required 'js')
       - Variant 'desktopRuntimeElements-published' capability cafe.adriel.voyager:voyager-screenmodel:1.1.0-alpha01 declares a library for use during runtime:
           - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'jvm' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'wasm'
           - Other compatible attributes:
               - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
               - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.wasm.target (required 'js')
       - Variant 'desktopSourcesElements-published' capability cafe.adriel.voyager:voyager-screenmodel:1.1.0-alpha01 declares a component for use during runtime:
           - Incompatible because this component declares documentation, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'jvm' and the consumer needed a library, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'wasm'
           - Other compatible attributes:
               - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
               - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.wasm.target (required 'js')
       - Variant 'iosArm64ApiElements-published' capability cafe.adriel.voyager:voyager-screenmodel:1.1.0-alpha01 declares a library for use during 'kotlin-api':
           - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'wasm'
           - Other compatible attributes:
               - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
               - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.wasm.target (required 'js')
       - Variant 'iosArm64MetadataElements-published' capability cafe.adriel.voyager:voyager-screenmodel:1.1.0-alpha01 declares a library:
           - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during 'kotlin-metadata', as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native' and the consumer needed a component for use during 'kotlin-api', as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'wasm'
           - Other compatible attributes:
               - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
               - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.wasm.target (required 'js')
       - Variant 'iosArm64SourcesElements-published' capability cafe.adriel.voyager:voyager-screenmodel:1.1.0-alpha01:
           - Incompatible because this component declares documentation for use during 'kotlin-runtime', as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native' and the consumer needed a library for use during 'kotlin-api', as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'wasm'
           - Other compatible attributes:
               - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
               - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.wasm.target (required 'js')


...

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
```

Assume, something was done totally wrong... Would rely on your assistance. What is the right way to add dependencies into the KMP project?

## Update

Looks like it's been found the problem - https://github.com/adrielcafe/voyager/issues/269. In that case, the question is - "What can be used instead for the routing in KMP?"

Comment: Looking at the library's Setup page, it doesn't look like it ships with a Gradle plugin - where in the instructions do you see that it requires adding the `id = "cafe.adriel.voyager"` plugin dependency? Try removing the Gradle plugin setup code and rebuild, the way you're adding the `navigator` and `screenModel` dependencies looks correct.

Comment: I've been trying different variants. With the plugin definition and without it... Just stuck on adding a new dependency into the demo project (generated from the wizard usage https://kmp.jetbrains.com with everything checked: Web, Desktop, Mobile).

Comment: What errors are you seeing when you're not adding the Gradle plugin dependency? Can you please update your question to include those errors? Please also note that adding the `"androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.7.0@aar"` dependency to the `commonMain` source set like you do in the "Update" section won't work, since `navigation-compose` is an Android library, hence you can only add it to `android` source sets: it does not support platforms other than Android.

Comment: I've repeated example from https://github.com/adrielcafe/voyager/blob/main/samples/android/src/main/java/cafe/adriel/voyager/sample/androidViewModel/AndroidListScreen.kt . Without library it's returned "Unresolved reference: cafe"

Comment: Are you able to clone the library repo from Github and build this sample as is on your machine? If yes then you'll need to look for differences in your configuration vs the sample. If no - I'd report a Github issue, as there could potentially be an issue with the library itself.

Comment: That example is not fully relevant to my targets by using KMP (while the mentioned is for Android). Without additional modules the https://kmp.jetbrains.com project works locally, but I'm failing on adding any of libs for routing.

Comment: It would be really helpful if you updated the question providing as much detail as possible about the latest errors you've seen, and removing the Gradle plugin code, and the "Update" section, as those approaches clearly won't work.

Comment: I've dropped everything except the main case.

Comment: Looks like I've found the problem - https://github.com/adrielcafe/voyager/issues/269. In that case, the question is - "What can be used instead for the routing?"

Comment: Questions looking for library recommendations aren't a good fit for Stackoverflow, I'm voting to close the question as it seems that you were able to resolve your original problem.

Comment: With bounty is cannot be closed. Will do that after 7 days... nonetheless, some recommendations would be appreciated.

Comment: Note: PR 289 (Kotlin WASM support) is completed in [`adrielcafe/voyager` release 1.1.0-alpha03](https://github.com/adrielcafe/voyager/releases/tag/1.1.0-alpha03). I have updated [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77734243/6309) accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [issue 269](https://github.com/adrielcafe/voyager/issues/269#issuecomment-1845440740) mentioned:

> Kotlin WASM is only available in the Compose Multiplatform alphas, Voyager will likely only include support once it's included in a stable version of Compose.

---

> What can be used instead for the routing in KMP?

Since there is no obvious alternative, you need to monitor [`adrielcafe/voyager` PR 289](https://github.com/adrielcafe/voyager/pull/289), which is about adding the support for Kotlin WASM and updating the Compose to 1.6.0-alpha01.

<del>This is still in progress</del>.

Feb. 2024: [`adrielcafe/voyager` PR 289](https://github.com/adrielcafe/voyager/pull/289) is now completed, with [commit 22cbd62](https://github.com/adrielcafe/voyager/commit/22cbd6295167336c719d76ab9472d2b85c9ac68d):

> ### Kotlin WASM support
>
> ```kotlin
> fun Project.setupModuleForComposeMultiplatform(
>     withKotlinExplicitMode: Boolean = true,
>     fullyMultiplatform: Boolean = false,
>     enableWasm: Boolean = true,
>     iosPrefixName: String = "ios" // only used in ios sample
> ) {
> ```

The `enableWasm: Boolean = true,` parameter is new.

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin WASM support is added in voyager `1.1.0-alpha03` version. Use that.